# How to assign a text file's lines of integers into 2D tables in Java?

Tags: java, file, line

I have the sample.txt which contains 100 Integers (range 0-9) in every line formatted like this:

```
9 2 0 3 4 1 0 7 5 3 7 8 6 2 0 1 4 4 5 9 0 3 2 1 7 (etc... 100 numbers)
```

I want to scan the file and put every line into a 10x10 table. So:

```
public void loadTableFromFile(String filepath){

    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath)))) {

        String line;
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {

        // WHAT HERE? THIS BLOCK DOES NOT WORK
        /*    if (s.hasNextInt()) {
                //take int and put it in the table in the right position procedure
            } else {
                s.next();
            }  */
        // END OF NOT WORKING BLOCK

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: what is happening???... what do u mean by "Not Working?"

Comment: Your outcommented block does not do anything except iterate over the line's integers. Or did you omit code in the if(s.HasNextInt()) { ... } brackets?

Comment: @zerocool I tried to use theese functions in the "not working codeblock" to get my integers in the table but didn't work.

Comment: @TheLostMind see reply to zerocool

Comment: @scd see reply to zerocool

Comment: As I was saying, if you used the code as you posted it, it won't do anything, since it only checks if the scanner has a readable int - if yes, it does nothing, if not, it goes to the next readable input. You are not doing anything with your read integers. See the posted answers for code that does what you are asking for.

Comment: @scd I edited post so you can see that the block if (s.hasNextInt()) {} wasn't blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
public void loadTableFromFile(String filepath) {
  Scanner s = null; // Our scanner.
  try {
    s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
        new FileReader(filepath))); // get it from the file.
    String line;
    while (s.hasNextLine()) { // while we have lines.
      line = s.nextLine(); // get a line.
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
      int i = 0;
      while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        if (i != 0) {
          System.out.print(' '); // add a space between elements.
        }
        System.out.print(st.nextToken().trim()); // print the next element.
        i++;
        if (i % 10 == 0) { // Add a new line every ten elements.
          System.out.println();
        }
      }
      System.out.println(); // between lines.
    }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    if (s != null)
      s.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that reads the line of the file into an array of strings using the split by whitespace method, and then reads them in using a for loop. I threw any exceptions that might have occurred in the method declaration, alternatively, use the try catch loop as above (might be better design, not sure about that.)

```
public void loadTableFromFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String[] line = br.readLine().split(" ");
    br.close(); // file only has 1 line with 100 integers

    int[][] mydata = new int[10][10];

    for(int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
        mydata[i % 10][(int) (i / 10)] = Integer.parseInt(line[i]);
    }

}
```

Now, if the file has more than one line, you could instead read the entire file line by line, and then use the above idea like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
String line1;
while((line1 = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] line = line1.split(" ");
    ... // do above stuff of reading in 1 line here
}
br.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath)))) {

    String line;
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
     String[] strArr=line.split(" ");

     for(int i=0;i<strArr.length;i++){
       System.out.print(" "+strArr[i]);
       if((i+1)%10==0){
       System.out.println();
       }
     }

    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){

}
```